# Using with CUBE on the same column twice to output perculated results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hypothetically, I have a table that consists of int values only one column with values like `1,2,3` etc., called `Number`.

When I try:

```
SELECT Number,Number FROM Table Group By Number WITH CUBE
```

It returns:

```
Number  Number
------  ------
 1       1
 2       2
 3       3
```

I was expecting it to return something more like this:

```
Number  Number
------  ------
 1       1
 1       2
 1       3
 2       1
 2       2
 2       3
```

and so forth... (with every combination)

How would this be possible, `WITH CUBE` doesn't seem to be cutting it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want the cartesian product:

```
SELECT a.Number, b.Number 
FROM [Table] a, [Table] b
```

Or, another way to write:

```
SELECT a.Number, b.Number 
FROM [Table] a CROSS JOIN [Table] b
```

Comment: that's it. Another way `[TABLE] a CROSS APPLY [Table] b` ...just for completeness